# Internal compiler error: killed (program cc1plus) on MAC OS Sierra

Tags: macos, tensorflow, gcc, compiler-errors

doing a compilation on MAC... (ps: for mxnet...)

got an error msg...

CMakeFiles/mxnet_static.dir/src/operator/tensor/indexing_op.cc.o -c /work/mxnet/src/operator/tensor/indexing_op.cc
armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabi-g++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report...

doing some search it seems this may be due to insufficient RAM
(test on my two MAC one 8G and another 16GB RAM.. both have the same error)

Q1: does that look like the case - insufficient mem? 
Q2: if so, how to increase virtual MEM on MAC OS? running Sierra 10.12 and 10.13

or other suggestions?

thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 7):

problem solved...

i reboot my build machine and close most applications.
this clean up my memory.  I then redo the build and the build went through just fine.

Just a reference for others..